# POP3 and SMTP access at the same time?

Tags: vb.net, smtp, pop3

I am looking to write a VB.Net program that can send and receive emails that contain data in attachments. I'm planning to use [MailBee.Net](http://www.afterlogic.com/mailbee-net/email-components) for this. My question is, is it possible to perform both sending and receiving actions at the exact same time? That is, using multi-threading? If yes, how would I do this in VB.Net?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to test it out is to use two [BackgroundWorkers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx) on your form and have the Do_Work methods do your basic sending and receiving.  You can use the [ReportProgress](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ka89zff4.aspx) method to update your UI thread with a percentage complete.

It looks like that component mentions SMTP threading is possible, but doesn't mention if the POP3 is thread safe, but you can give it a shot and see if it works.